# Cocos2d-x 3.0 sequence of rotation with different anchor point

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to make a sequence which has 3 RotateBy actions.

1st RotateBy action with `ANCHOR_MIDDLE_TOP`

2nd RotateBy action with `ANCHOR_MIDDLE`

3rd RotateBy action with `ANCHOR_MIDDLE_BOTTOM`

But, I don't know how to run this sequence in the following order

1. `mySprite->setAnchorPoint(Point::ANCHOR_MIDDLE_TOP);`
2. rotate mySprite 90 degree
3. `mySprite->setAnchorPoint(Point::ANCHOR_MIDDLE);`
4. rotate mySprite 90 degree
5. `mySprite->setAnchorPoint(Point::ANCHOR_MIDDLE_BOTTOM);`
6. rotate mySprite 90 degree

And Sequence::create takes only actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CallFunc` as an action, and call a function that changes the anchor point of your sprite.  Something like this:

```
cocos2d::Sequence::create(cocos2d::RotateBy::create(1.0f, 90.0f),  
    cocos2d::CallFunc::create(MySprite::changeAnchorPoint),
    cocos2d::RotateBy::create(1.0f, 90.0f),  
    cocos2d::CallFunc::create(MySprite::changeAnchorPoint),
    cocos2d::RotateBy::create(1.0f, 90.0f),  
    cocos2d::CallFunc::create(MySprite::changeAnchorPoint));
```

***Edit:*** to send a parameter you should be able to write something like this:

```
cocos2d::CallFunc::create([mySprite]() { 
    mySprite->setAnchorPoint(Point::ANCHOR_MIDDLE_TOP); 
});
```

***Note:*** CallFunc wants a function with no parameters, but you can get around that by capturing your object you'd like to use in the function using the c++11 lambda syntax.

Comment: I don't want to write a separate function. So, I would like to use `CallFuncN::create(mySprite->setAnchorPoint, ???)` But, don't know what will be its second parameter for callback. I want to call `setAnchorPoint(Point::ANCHOR_MIDDLE)` or did I misunderstood about CallFuncN.

Comment: @Balakrishnan see my edit, I'm pretty sure that will work, but opening up my editor to double check

Comment: I have written like this `CallFunc::create(CC_CALLBACK_1(mySprite->setAnchorPoint, Point::ANCHOR_MIDDLE_TOP))` even the IDE(Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012) didn't detect any syntax error. But, I get many build errors.

Comment: If you are trying to call a function on a seperate object I believe the syntax is a bit different for some reason launching up the latest cocos2d-x build and making a test proj is giving me lots of build errors at the moment so I can't give much more guidance at the moment.

Comment: But, did the solution will be like what you posted? I mean that did I have to use CC_CALLBACK_1 and CallFunc for sure.

Comment: It seems CallFunc always takes a function with no parameters, and CallFuncN takes a function with a parameter of type cocos2d::Node, there used to be an option for whatever parameter you want, but it doesn't seem to exist at the moment without using something deprecated

Comment: I found it `cocos2d::CallFunc::create([mySprite]() { mySprite->setAnchorPoint(Point::ANCHOR_MIDDLE_TOP); })` Key is to use C++11 lambda function.

Comment: Ah nice work around, it's still a parameterless function, but it captures your `mySprite` object.  I like it, I'll edit my answer with that in case someone stumbles on this question in the future